# Using two Repositories in one Cubit - Flutter BLoC

Tags: flutter, dart, bloc

I was wondering if I could **instantiate two Repositories** in **one Cubit** ? Like so :

```
class LoginCubit extends Cubit<LoginState> {  
LoginCubit(this._authRepository, this._authenticationRepository) 
     : super(const LoginState());  

final FirebaseAuthRepository _authenticationRepository;  

final AuthRepository _authRepository;
```

I get stuck on what to do when I'd like to use my cubit :

```
BlocProvider(create: (_) => LoginCubit(context.read<AuthRepository, FirebaseAuthRepository>()),
```

I get this linter error :

`-> 2 positional argument(s) expected, but 1 found. Try adding the missing arguments.`

Comment: if you have both AuthRepo and firebaseRepo in context tree then this should work

LoginCubit(context.read<AuthRepository>(), context.read<FirebaseAuthRepository>())

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Absolutely no problem to have multiple repositories in a Cubit. Your constructor call is the problem. You need to pass two variables to the cubits constructor. I.e.:

```
LoginCubit(firstParameter, secondParameter)
```

Then how you get those parameters can differ...

You could do e.g.:

```
LoginCubit(AuthRepository(), FirebaseAuthRepository())
```

or:

```
LoginCubit(context.read<AuthRepository>(), context.read<FirebaseAuthRepository>()),
```

or however you get your two repositories...

May I suggest you to look into the service locator package named `getIt` together with the package named `injectable`. Then those things will be solved for you...

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help ! Do you have any example ressources working together with Cubit or BLoC for those packages ?

Comment: I've made a similar answer earlier here on SO. Replace MyClass with your `LoginCubit`, and use the `getIt<T>()` call in your BlocProvider-create-call instead of manually creating `LoginCubit()`.  The answer is here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72415554/difference-between-using-getit-and-declaring-your-own-instances/72418884#72418884